# What is the typical package naming convention for Spring-Batch projects?

Tags: spring-batch

I am implementing my first Spring-Batch application. In the naming of the packages, the Samples project names each domain in its own package with readers-writers-processors all in one package for the respective domain (i.e. football game).  Is that typical?

Say, for example, I have jobs to read-process-write for 10 different flat files.  Should I have 10 different packages with each package containing the readers-processors-writers for each respective file/job?

Or, could it be equally reasonable to have one 'readers' package for all the readers, and a 'processors' package for all the processors, and a 'writers' package for all writers.

I'm interfacing with an SAP system, and over time, the number of files we process will grow.  So, I'm trying to get a smarter handle on what's better, in terms of naming and organizing my packages.  And, I want to do it the way the Spring-Batch community would do it.

Thanks.

Comment: i would go with the package per job pattern, makes it easier to refactor to individual projects later

Comment: Thnank you very much, @MichaelPralow.  I will take that to the bank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the first solution,but perhaps adding an extra package for complex jobs containing many steps, for example: `com.company.software.batch.jobName.stepName`

Then you will have a clear functional view of all your jobs.

Comment: Not knowing any better, I went with com.company.batch.domain.jobName for the launcher then extended from there by object.  (i.e. com.company.batch.domain.jobName.writers, ...jobName.processors, ...jobName.readers, ...jobName.tasklets, ...jobName.validators, ...jobName.listeners, ...jobName.enums, etc.)  Thank you for the suggestion.  I like it.